# Matrix and vector norms Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, numerical-methods

I want to prove that  $\frac{\left \| u - \tilde{u} \right \|}{\left \| u \right \|}\leq \frac{k(A)}{1-k(A)\frac{\left \| A - \tilde{A} \right \|}{\left \| A \right \|}} \frac{\left \| A - \tilde{A} \right \|}{\left \| A \right \|}$ , where

$A$ and $\tilde{A}$ are non singular ( $Au=s$ , $\tilde{A}\tilde{u}=s$ ) and $\left \| A-\tilde{A} \right \| < 1/\left \| A^{-1} \right \|$.

Also $\tilde{A}$ is a slightly changed version of $A$ and k is the condition number.

I don't know how I should work with the left part of the inequality. I've thought replacing $\tilde{A}$ with $A+δΑ$ and $\tilde{u}$ with $u +δu$, but I am not pretty sure how I should deal with it. Could anyone give me some ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$p={||\delta u||\over||u||},\quad q={||\delta A||\over||A||}\implies kq=||A^{-1}||\cdot||\delta A||$$To prove
$$
p\le{k||\delta A||\over ||A||-k||\delta A||}\iff p\le{1\over{1\over{kq}}-1}
\iff {1\over p}\ge {1\over kq}-1\\
\iff {||u||+||\delta u||\over ||\delta u||}\ge{1\over kq}\iff||A^{-1}||\cdot||\delta A||\cdot(||u||+||\delta u||)\ge ||\delta u||
$$
It suffices to prove
$$
||A^{-1}||\cdot||\delta A||\cdot||u+\delta u||\ge ||\delta u||
$$
Note that
$$
(A+\delta A)(u+\delta u)=Au\implies\delta A(u+\delta u)=-A\delta u\implies A^{-1}\delta A(u+\delta u)=-\delta u\\
$$
Using the inequality $||AB||\le||A||\cdot||B||$ twice and the identity $||-x||=||x||$ once we get the desired inequality.

Use of the given condition:
$$
||A^{-1}||\cdot||\delta A||<1\implies kq<1\implies {1\over kq} -1>0
$$
So the condition ensures the denominator in the RHS of the inequality is positive or non-zero.

Comment: Can't thank you enough!!!